# How do I link to an anchor within a Structure Page?

Tags: structure

**(Edit 7/17/2014) Forgot to mention earlier:** I am using ExpressionEngine, Wygwam, and Structure together.

I can set link type to "link to anchor in text"... but that's only for the current document...

Alternately I can set link type to "structure page"...

But how can I set link type to "anchor within structure page"? It's not an option, but is there a way to do it?

I know I can hardcode the link in by setting link type to "URL" and just typing it in with the #anchor at the end... but I am trying to avoid this so that the link will work in the future if I change the page name/location within structure.

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? Is this in a wysiwyg editor or what?

Comment: Wygwam, inside of expressionengine... sorry forgot to mention

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without writing your own (wysiwyg or EE) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could append #whatever to {page_url} so that's it always dynamic. The anchor itself could even be drawn from a custom field within entries.

Comment: Hi Travis... sorry this doesn't make sense to me... I forgot to mention earlier that I'm dealing with Wygwam inside of ExpressionEngine. For links, there is an option for a URL where you type in any URL you like. But if you're using Structure, you can also choose a Structure page within your site structure. This is the option I want to take as it allows for changes later (if I move the page in structure, it will automatically update my links). There is no {page_url} I can add a #anchor to. Your comment seems to suggest a template approach, but I am dealing with content here, not the template.